# Meaning of "* */1 * * *" cron entry?

Tags: cron

Somehow, I am finding it difficult to understand tweaking around `*` parameters with cron.

I wanted a job to run every hour and I used the below setting:

```
* */1 * * *
```

But it does not seem to do the job. Could someone please explain the meaning of above and what is needed for the job?

Comment: Okay, I understand now: The problem is with the * mark, I have put in minute place...*/1 and * in hour place probably mean the same thing though..

Comment: Actually, that looks like it would run every minute! If it is not running at all then you have another problem. What is the string that comes after the part that you posted?

Comment: https://crontab.guru/#*/3_4_*_*_*

Answer (score 27, accepted):

- `*` means *every*.
- `*/n` means *every nth*. (So `*/1` means *every 1*.)

If you want to run it only once each hour, you have to set the first item to something else than `*`, for example `20 * * * *` to run it every hour at minute `20`.

Or if you have permission to write in /etc/cron.hourly/ (or whatever it is on your system), then you could place a script there.

Comment: I thought n, means every nth. What is the difference between n and 1/n then?

Comment: `n` means exactly at _n_. Like above, 20 means _at minute 20_. `1/n` means _starting from 1, every nth_. However in practice this is used as `1-2/n`, meaning _in interval from 1 to 2, every nth_. (Note that not all `cron` implementations supports intervals.)

Answer (score 13):

The `*/1` is redundant, you should use `*` instead.

```
* */1 * * *
```

does not run the job every hour, runs it every minute!
To run a job every hour (at 1:00, 2:00, etc.) use

```
0 * * * *
```

Comment: This the explanation was was looking for . Thanks